# How can I prove that this subset $C$ is closed in $C[0,1]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

> Let $C=\{f\in C[0,1]: f(0)=f(1)\}$. I need to show that $C$ is closed in $C[0,1]$ with respect to $||f||_{\infty}=\max(f)$.

I know that I can define $\phi(f)=f(0)-f(1)$ and then argue that $\phi$ is continuous and $C=\phi^{-1}(\{0\})$. But I wanted to do it in another way:

**Proof**
Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence in $C$ s.t. $$f_n\stackrel{||\cdot||_\infty}{\longrightarrow}f\in C[0,1]$$ I want to show that $f\in C$. But now consider $$\begin{align}|f_n(0)-f(0)|&\leq\max_x|f_n(x)-f(x)|\\&=||f_n-f||_\infty\rightarrow0\end{align}$$Similarly for $f_n(1)$. So we get $\lim_nf_n(0)=f(0)$ and $\lim_nf_n(1)=f(1)$, but since the limit is unique and for all $n$ we have $f_n(0)=f_n(1)$, we deduce that $f(0)=f(1)$ and therefore $f\in C$.

Now my question is does this work or am I wrong?

Comment: yes it works ! $ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: @Surb perfect thanks a lot!

Comment: You can as well apply $\varphi.$ We have $0=\varphi(f_n)\to \varphi(f).$ Therefore $\varphi(f)=0.$ For this you need continuity of $\varphi,$ which follows from $|\varphi(g)|\le 2\|g\|_\infty.$

Comment: Yes. If $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly (i.e. in the $\sup$ norm) then $f_n$ must converge point-wise to $f$.

Comment: Another  way is to show the complement is open: If $f\in C[0,1]$ \  $C$, let $r=|f(0)-f(1)|.$ Then $r>0$. The open ball $\{g\in C[0,1]:\|f-g\|<r/2\}$ contains $f$ and is disjoint from $C$.